# Architecture for Decentralized Application

Tags: architecture, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ipfs

I have been learning SOLIDITY for quite a bit and am ready to do projects. I wanted to make a cool project where we store transaction details in form of PDF into blockchain and all those details are recorded in blockchain.

Like take example of persons health report. His initial health report is stored in blockchain. Later if someone wants to change that they cant using blockchain right?

I want to build such projects using ethereum and IPFS.

I would like to know architecture and someuseful resources to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Emercoin NVS](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emernvs) for your purpose, and store within NVS your IPFS hash. So, by searchable name, you can extract from blockchain your IPFS hash, and by hash - you can extract from IPFS your file object (PDF or so).

NVS allows to use command "name_update", when you assign for a search name another value (new IPFS hash). Of course, old values also kept in the blockchain, and you can extract history of the updates with a command "name_history".

I recommend you to create prototype with [Emercoin Testnet](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/running-emercoin/testnet). If you need testnet EMCs for your experiments - ask me, I'll provide for free.